# Rails 3 ActiveAdmin. How to disable the Dashboard for users with a non-admin role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, activeadmin

This is how I can see user's role: `current_admin_user.role`

I'm using CanCan

How can I

1. Hide the Dashboard button
2. Restrict access to the Dashboard in case the user finds out it's url

-
I have tried this but doesn't work.

```
dashboard_controller.rb
if current_admin_user.role == 'customer'
  redirect_to shipments_path
end
```

I tried this in admin/dashboards.rb

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    if current_admin_user.role == 'customer'
      redirect_to shipments_path
    end
  end
end
```

but produces error `undefined method 'controller' for ActiveAdmin::Dashboards:Module (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you know this place: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/501, some good ideas about dashboards over there.

Render a partial within your dashboards.rb file with something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin::Dashboards.build do

  section 'Common', :priority => 1 do
    div do
      render 'common_dashboard'
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Then from the partial, which you should create at                                                                app/views/admin/dashboard/_common_dashboard.html.erb you can access the current_admin_user object:

```
<ul>
  <li><%= current_admin_user.role %></li>
</ul>
```

Another way to get access to the current_admin_user from the dashboards.rb '''environment''' is to use the arbre syntax and formulate your dashboard sections like so

```
section "Common",:priority => 1 do 
  div do     
    if current_admin_user.role == "customer"
      li "You are a customer"
    end
  end
  '' 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Aslo you can restrict dashboard sections with :if conditions,
so dashboard will be available for all users but only with allowed sections

```
section("Recent Users", :if => proc{ can?(:manage, User) }) do
  ul do
    User.limit(10).order('created_at desc').collect do |user|
      li link_to(user.name, admin_user_path(user))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access controller action `redirect_to` just inside dashboard section in this way:

```
section do
  if current_admin_user.role == 'customer'
    controller.redirect_to shipments_path #any path you have in application
  else
    div do
    ...
    end
  end
```